# Regex Replace Simple String

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to write a piece of code using regex that let's my replace ANY value inside my parenthesis.  Take the following cases

Target text: build (123)

```
build (##-build-##)
build (111)
build (xxyyzz)
```

In all cases I want to find the word "build (***)" on the page, and replace it with my desired value.

Comment: Is there the possibility of nested parens?

Comment: Nope.  This is just a hidden snippet of text at the bottom of our site for testers to look at.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
\b(build \()[^)]+(\))
```

with:

```
\1yourreplacementhere\2
```

Comment: Uh? Won't this match only if the `build` part is the entire string?

Comment: Well, yes, and given the samples the OP has given, it looks like it will be the case. At least nothing tells otherwise (edit: no, I am mistaken, will edit).

Comment: "In all cases I want to find the word "build (*)" on the page" - I took this to mean that it was supposed to search the page... could be wrong though

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, but be aware that it will disregard nested parenthesis:

```
var pattern = @"build \((.+)\)";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
string[] strings =
{
    "build (##-build-##)",
    "build (111)",
    "build (xxyyzz)"
};
var results = strings.
    Select(s => regex.Replace(s, "(foo)")).
    ToArray();
//results = {build (foo), build(foo), build(foo)}
```

Comment: "be aware that it will disregard nested parenthesis" <-- OP says there  can't be any, so this is safe. THere is another concern though, the word can appear several time in a page: your first `.+` will swallow all until the end and give back to the last paren...

Comment: @fge I'm aware of the context the author wants to use it in, but I've adapted the example to map the input he provided to the desire output. It's unclear for me if he wants the `Regex` to operate on the entire page or on the strings taken singularly.

Comment: Well, OP says 'I want to find the word "build (*)" on the page', so... (and the fix is easy: use a complemented character class)

Comment: @fge I still think that the question was ambiguous. I'll edit my post making the pattern more specific. I didn't understand your first concern, about `.+`; he capitalized "ANY", which made me think that even whitespaces and new lines count.

Comment: I was a bit unclear, but I want to read in the entire contents of a file, find this string, and then replace it, and rewrite back out the file.

Comment: @Eve try your initial regex with `build (a) build (b)` and see what happens

Comment: @fge I understand what you meant now. I guess that still counted as "ANY". +1 for your way.

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern `(?<=build\s)\([^)]*\)`:

```
var input = "build (##-build-##)";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=build\s)\([^)]*\)", "new value");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: That will also remove the parens, if I have read correctly the OP wants to replace the value inside them, not remove them altogether

Comment: @fge Easy enough to throw parens into the new value, but should probably be mentioned in the answer.